# after removing index.php from url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My login Controller : `$this->load->view('login-view');`

My link that redirects to 'login-view' is in the template is: `anchor('login','Login');`

Before removing index.php from url in codeigniter works well. But after removing index.php from url it is not working.

My .htaccess file is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

hard to expalin i think, Thats all i have got. :(

Comment: And it still works if you call it like `index.php/login`?

Comment: Have you set up config.php and routes.php?

Comment: index.php/login works... but index.php is showing in the url...

Comment: sry not to mention... I'm working in wamp, offline

Comment: i have set up my config.php like $config['uri_protocol']= 'REQUEST_URI';

and $route['default_controller'] = "home";

Comment: Is `mod_rewite` enabled for Apache on WAMP server?

Comment: Oops! success! i placed my htaccess file in the application folder before, now it is in my root directory... Thank u all for suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Try this in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And in `config.php`

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: not working... :(

anchor('index.php/login','Login') is working but url contains (site)/index.php/login

Comment: Oops! success! i placed my htaccess file in the application folder before, now it is in my root directory... Thank u all for suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Just remove index.php from your config file.

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

should be

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```